# How do I change the value of a variable inside a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm trying to simplify the error message since on my project it's expected to print a lot of errors.
I tried this simple example but nothing seems to work.

How can I make it so 'n' iterates and actually prints the position where there is an error?
It always prints as if 'n=1'.

```
n = 1
error = f"Error word {n}"

def test(word):
    if len(word)>5:
        print(error)

ar = ['pizza', 'toasts', 'ham', 'mayo', 'houses']
for word in ar:
    test(word)
    n+=1
```

I've tried

```
error = f"Error word {n}"
```

```
error = 'Error word '+ str(n)
```

```
error = "Error word {n}".format(n)
```

But maybe I'm not looking at the issue the correct way?

Comment: You don't have "a variable inside a string". You have a string you built based on the value a variable had at a certain point in time. It has no lingering connection to the variable. If you want new text, you have to build a new string.

Comment: As soon as the second line is run, `error` will include whatever the value of `n` is at that point. You need to recreate the `error` string each time `n` changes to include different values of `n`. Strings are immutable, so they can't be changed once they're created.

Comment: You need to (re)set error inside the function when it is called, or constantly (re)set it whenever n is changed

Comment: A string type is insufficient for this usecase. Perhaps a function that takes in `n` as an argument and prints the error would be more appropriate?

Comment: also, you might check out what `enumerate(ar)` does for you.

Comment: @JeJe I believe OP wants to print `f"Error word {n}"` where n is the counter of the for loop, not `f"Error word {word}"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because the line:

```
error = f"Error word {n}"
```

Just puts the initial value of n into the string, aka 1 and will not update with the loop.(In other words, the string is stuck as "Error word 1")

Heres the updated code:

```
n = 1
error = "Error word"


def test(word):
    if len(word) > 5:
        print(error, ': ', n)


ar = ['pizza', 'toasts', 'ham', 'mayo', 'houses']
for word in ar:
    test(word)
    n+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

because n is outside the loop. the code once executed is not updating the value on n in line number 2. it is something like error = 'Error word 1'

Comment: n = 1

def test(word):
    if len(word)>5:
        print(f"Error word {n}")

ar = ['pizza', 'toasts', 'ham', 'mayo', 'houses']
for word in ar:
    test(word)
    n=n+1

Comment: As you see, comments aren't meant for writing code. Please [edit] your answer to include the code, and don't forget to [format](/help/formatting) it correctly with a code block!

Answer (score 0):

You don't. f-strings will use the variable values at the point they are "seen" in the source code - and afterwards they will behave just as plain strings.

The way to do late-binding of variables is to use the classic `.format` method for strings, instead of query strings: you have to pass in the variables to be replaced as arguments in the `.format` call:

The problem you hit when trying to use `format` is that there are some different modes to use it: just use plain `" ... {} ..."`, with nothing in between, will be replaced by the first positional argument in format. But if you a named variable like in `"{n}"`, you have to pass a named argument in the format call.

This would work:

```
n = 1
error = "Error word {n}"   # without the f-prefix:  a plain string

def test(word):
    if len(word)>5:
 
        print(error.format(n=n))
```

here, the `n` before the `=` is the name that shows in the string, between the `{n}` markers. The `n` after the `=` is the value, in this case, the global variable `n`

As a side note, this is not a good design for functions: you should pass to it all data it will need as arguments, and not rely on `n` as a global variable:

```
def test(word, n):
    if len(word)>5:
        print(error.format(n=n))

ar = ['pizza', 'toasts', 'ham', 'mayo', 'houses']
for word in ar:
    test(word, n)
    n+=1
```

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer `.format` over simply using the f-string literal where the formatted string is needed?

Comment: It can be an option when you have a project where the structure would favor not putting string messages along with the logic - and rather keep then in a different place/file where it will be edited by other people not involved with the code. 

For smaller/ordinary projects, there is no difference, and being able to use the much more practical f-strings is an argument for just defining the strings where they are used.

Answer (score 0):

Python evaluates f-strings at runtime, and at that time of evaluating it the result is `"Error word 1"` which is stored as a string.

What you might also do is use `enumerate`, and set the starting value to 1

```
ar = ['pizza', 'toasts', 'ham', 'mayo', 'houses']

for n, word in enumerate(ar, 1):
    if len(word) > 5:
        print(f"Error word {n}")
```